# Fetch the text value of Nobr based on child td

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I wan't to fetch the text of nobr based on child td. MY HTML is below in screen shot[image]

I tried like this but it gives me empty value

```
$("[id^='FormatShouldReturnas']").parent('td nobr').text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `textContent` and `innerText` properties.

```
var text = $("[id^='FormatShouldReturnas']").parent('td nobr').textContent ? $("[id^='FormatShouldReturnas']").parent('td nobr').textContent : $("[id^='FormatShouldReturnas']").parent('td nobr').innerText;
```

Note that IE8 (as well as IE9, 10, and 11 when running in compatibility mode) will use `innerText`, while other browsers will use `textContent`.

**Update**:

```
$("#FormatShouldReturnas").parent().find('nobr').text();
```

The above code is tested and works fine.

Comment: i tried it and it says no function with parent

Comment: @sandy143 I have updated the code, please check.